# Incrementing to next id in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image I click which brings me to a page with some info and two buttons which are previous and next.

My code keeps going back to the same slide. How would I increment my "id" attribute to add +1 on my id attribute every time I click the next button or -1 for previous?

Here is my code

```
    $(".portfolioLink").click(function(){

        // Hide slide and portfolio piece info
        $(".inner-content.portfolio").show();

        // Reset slides timer and pagination
        clearInterval($('#slides').data('interval'));
        $("ul.pagination li").removeClass("current");

        var slideID = $(this).parent().next().attr("id");

        $("#next").click(function() {
            slideswitch(slideID);
        });
    }
```

Comment: There is too much missing information here. Where is slideswitch? What variable are you trying to increment?

Comment: Slideswitch is a function I run. I am trying to increment the slideID variable.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var slideID = $(this).parent().next().attr("id");
slideID = 1 + parseInt(slideID);
```

if the ID has some text to it (id = "div1" for example) you can write the id number:

```
var slideID = $(this).attr("id").match(/\d+/);
```

Comment: I am still getting the same number just +1 everytime.

Comment: The id represents the particular number of slide you are on.

Comment: If I console log it out when I click on an item with an id of 1, it brings me back an item of 3 repeatedly.

Comment: i mean is it just a number or a number and text?

Comment: wiered.. works for me.. mind getting your code online to http://jsfiddle.net/ ? it will be easier to help you this way

Comment: It's impossible to help without seeing the html. might be that you have a problem with `$(this).parent().next().attr("id");`

Comment: yeah thats what I am looking at.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20700/discussion-between-wowzuzz-and-kuf)

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to separate the base part of your id from the numerical part. Then parse the numerical part as an int and increment or decrement it as needed. Then concatenation it back on the the base part of your id.